# ¿Como invertir arreglos multidimensionales en java?

Tags: java, array

Necesito invertir los valores de un arreglo, donde si por ejemplo me sale

> 1 5 2
>  4 1 5 
>  9 4 6

me aparezcan así,

> 9 4 6 
>  4 1 5 
>  1 5 2

este es mi método, me imprime ciertos valores en 0, necesito ver que puede ser
son 2 vectores, vector2d1 el principal del que saco los valores y el aux al que los guardo vector2d2

```
for (int i = 0; i < vector2d1.length /2; i++) {
    for (int c = 0; c < vector2d1.length  ; c++) {
       vector2d2[i][c] = vector2d1[i][c];
       vector2d1[i][c] = vector2d1[vector2d1.length - 1][c];
       vector2d1[vector2d1.length - 1][c] = vector2d2[i][c];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Lo tienes casi casi listo... solo que no haces el intercambio de forma apropiada con una variable "temporal" y restar el puntero `i` para que pueda invertir los datos de la forma que esperas.

```
for (int i = 0; i < vector2d1.length /2; i++) {
    for (int c = 0; c < vector2d1.length  ; c++) {
       int temp = vector2d1[i][c];
       vector2d1[i][c] = vector2d1[vector2d1.length - 1 - i][c];
       vector2d1[vector2d1.length - 1 - i][c] = temp;
    }
}
```

El gran agravante de este código es que va a fallar cuando la estructura del array no sea de iguales dimensiones, es decir cuando no sea igual en filas y columnas.

`verctor2d1.length` así tal cual devolverá el tamaño en filas, solamente eso, no te dará información del ancho del array 2d, por tanto, cuando se trata de un array de idénticas dimensiones no importará porque filas y columnas son iguales, todo ok, pero si tenemos por ejemplo un `vector2d1[3][5]` el segundo ciclo `for` el encargado de recorrer columnas solo llegara hasta 3 no hasta 5, ignorarías 2 columnas de datos!; Este comportamiento es posible corregirlo por ejemplo con `vector2d1[1].length`, que da el ancho.

Volviendo a tu código y modificando ahora ese segundo ciclo `for`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < vector2d1.length /2; i++) {
    for (int c = 0; c < vector2d1[1].length; c++) {
       int temp = vector2d1[i][c];
       vector2d1[i][c] = vector2d1[vector2d1.length - 1 - i][c];
       vector2d1[vector2d1.length - 1 - i][c] = temp;
    }
}
```

Ya el programa es mas generico invirtiendo las filas de datos de la forma que planteas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Método que resuelve tu ejemplo:

```
public static void inversorArray(Object[][] arreglo) {
    for(int i = 0; i < (arreglo.length / 2); i++) {
        Object[] temp = arreglo[i];
        arreglo[i] = arreglo[arreglo.length - i - 1];
        arreglo[arreglo.length - i - 1] = temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: Me podrías explicar lo de recibir un (Object [] [] arreglo), no lo logro entender, Se supone que ahí debo de mandar el vector con los números ya generados? para posteriormente invertirlos

Comment: Envias tu array bidimensional `inversorArray(vector2d1);` y ese metodo convierte el mismo objeto `vector2d1 ` en el array invertido

Comment: No me está funcionando, se supone que ese vector lo tengo que sacar después para imprimirlo en un Jtable y solo me imprime puros 0

Comment: Tu array es `int[][]` o `Integer[][]`? Si es int intenta cambiarlo a un objeto Integer para que este metodo funcione.

Comment: Talvez me expliqué mal, Inicia el programa pidiendo renglones y columnas, creo 2 DefaultTableModel llamados Modelo1 y Modelo2 con los renglones y columnas para el final agregarlos a los jtable, Creo 2 vectores Int en el Form y en la clase, le llamo al metodo generarrandom y con un Get me traigo el valor del vector1, lo guardo en modelo1 y lo imprimo, después mando al metodo Ordenar, el que publiqué, para utilizar tu método como me traería el vector con los resultados?

Answer (score 0):

¡Ey, que tal amigo!

Esto fue lo que te entendí.

```
int[][] r = new int[3][3];
int[][] r2 = new int[3][3];
int cont = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < r.length; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < r.length; j++) {
        r[i][j] = cont;
        System.out.print(" " +r[i][j]);
        cont++;
    }
    System.out.println();
}
System.out.println();
```

El código anterior era para llenar el arreglo, lo que te sirve es lo que sigue:

```
for (int i = r.length-1; i >=0; i--) {
    for (int j = r.length-1; j >= 0; j--) {
        r2[i][j] = r[i][j];
        System.out.print(" " + r[i][j]);

    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Respuesta:

```
 1 2 3
 4 5 6
 7 8 9

 9 8 7
 6 5 4
 3 2 1
```

¡Espero te sirva, salu2!